# How to get GPS data from Waze with rest-client?

Tags: ruby, rest-client, waze

I'm trying to get my GPS data from the Waze app using the [rest-client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) lib. I'm basicly trying to fake a login via the website https://www.waze.com/. After login (you can use JohnDoeSpeedy228:gre@tStory92) when you visit https://www.waze.com/editor/, click on "Drives" after review the the network calls you'll get to see the raw JSON data.

I seem to have succesfully logged in but when making the request to return the list of all my drives it returns the following

```
{"users"=>{"objects"=>[]}, "archives"=>{"totalSessions"=>0, "objects"=>[]}}
```

It should return something like this:

```
{
   "users":{
      "objects":[

      ]
   },
   "archives":{
      "totalSessions":1,
      "objects":[
         {
            "id":<REDACTED>,
            "userID":<REDACTED>,
            "existingRoadMeters":2839,
            "newRoadMeters":0,
            "totalRoadMeters":2839,
            "startTime":1456996197000,
            "endTime":1456996636000,
            "hasFullSession":true
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here's what I'm trying:

```
require 'rest-client'
require 'json'

GET_CSRF_URL = "https://www.waze.com/login/get"
SESSION_URL = "https://www.waze.com/login/create"
SESSION_LIST_URL = "https://www.waze.com/Descartes-live/app/Archive/List"
SESSON_DATA_URL = "https://www.waze.com/Descartes-live/app/Archive/Session"
AUTH = {'user_id'=>'JohnDoeSpeedy228','password'=>'gre@tStory92'}

req = RestClient.get(GET_CSRF_URL)
csrfhash = req.cookies
csrfhash['editor_env'] = 'row'
headers = {'X-CSRF-Token'=>csrfhash['_csrf_token']}

log = RestClient::Request.execute(
  method: :post,
  url: SESSION_URL,
  cookies: csrfhash,
  headers: headers,
  payload: AUTH
)

ses = RestClient::Request.execute(
  method: :get,
  url: SESSION_LIST_URL,
  cookies: log.cookies,
  payload: {'minDistance'=>1000,'count'=>50, 'offset'=>0}
)

puts JSON.parse(ses)
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are confusing two accounts. Are you sure you logged a drive while logged in as JohnDoeSpeedy228? If there are no sessions from that user when logged into the site manually, I wouldn't expect the code to work either.

> We can't find any of your drives.
>
> Have you started driving with the Waze app yet? If so, please make sure you logged into the Map Editor with the same credentials you use in the app.

Comment: 100% no confusion of two accounts.

Comment: Yes, but my point is that if there are no recorded trips when you log on manually, why would you expect the REST API to return them?

Comment: There are three recorded trips.